# How to get function documentation in R Studio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to get documentation for some R functions in R Studio, but unfortunately when I press F1 I get windows help instead of documentation for particular function.

Comment: Enter `?` and then the name of a function (e.g. `?help`) in the console to look up a particular function, or `??` and then a pattern to search, e.g. `??help.search`

Comment: how do we get help on dot functions?  e.g. `> ?.rs.addApiFunction`
No documentation for ‘.rs.addApiFunction’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??.rs.addApiFunction’
`> ??.rs.addApiFunction` No results found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a **help** panel, probably on te right bottom corner. Press ctrl+3 to show it.